# $locationChangeStart not working for state ($stateProvider) change

Tags: angularjs

$locationChangeStart is not working when i change state from 'Home' to 'State' when Home page is dirty, but its working on closing browser and onclick of back button.

Below is the index.html page from where i am linking to 'Home' and 'About' page.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="homecontroller.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body ng-app="routerApp" ng-controller="homeCntrl">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Below is the index.js page where i have written code to display error message

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
       .state('home', {
           url: '/home',
           templateUrl: 'home.html'
       })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
        })
});

routerApp.controller('homeCntrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.Save = function () {
        alert('Save');
        $scope.form.myForm.$setPristine();
    }
});

routerApp.directive('confirmOnExit', function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if ($scope.form.myForm.$dirty) {
                    return "The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?";
                }
            }
            $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
                if ($scope.form.myForm.$dirty) {
                    if (!confirm("The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?")) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Below is the home.html page

```
<form name="form.myForm" confirm-on-exit>
    Name: <input name="input" ng-model="myModel.text">
    <p>myModel.text = {{form.myModel.text}}</p>
    <p>$pristine = {{form.myForm.$pristine}}</p>
    <p>$dirty = {{form.myForm.$dirty}}</p>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="Save()">Save</button>
</form>
```

Now i enter something in my input field (page becomes dirty) and click on 'About' tab. Url gets changed from home to about, but it is not hitting $locationChangeStart. But when i try to close broswer or click on back button it works fine.But everyone says $locationChangeStart is the way to identify on state change, but for me its not hitting there. How should i do for getting error message on state change?

below is the plunker (Note: ui-sref is not working here, but exact code working fine in my VS. I am not able to figure out why. But my problem is when i change link from Home to About when Home page is dirty then its not prompting error message)

https://plnkr.co/edit/LoGGusldqb74Zf5QGoOJ?p=preview

Comment: confirm-on-exit directive is only on home.html so it hits it only when you click home. Move $locationChangeStart on a shared controller.

Comment: i moved form from home.html to index.html, but the problem i am facing is when i click on 'About' it goes to About page first then it hits $locationChangeStart . How to handle this? I have updated the plunker.